# Is there a way to publish SQL Server database diagrams to html format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-diagramming

Currently, we model our databases in Rational Rose.  And, it provides the capability to export the database relationship diagrams to a html tree.  Does SQL Server or any other tool allow a similar output?  We'd like the ability to document our design and deliver it to our customer in an easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server can't do this (at least as of 2005). You can save the diagram as a bitmap (right click and select 'copy to clipboard'), but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks.  that's what I thought but just wanted a warm/fuzzy I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: Visio Pro 2003 lets you reverse engineer a diagram from a db, and then save to HTML, but then it saves a low res **image** - WTH?

Answer (score 0):

The [Erwin Data Modeler](http://erwin.com/products/data-modeler) offers the ability to export to HTML. I wish SSMS had more database diagram features.